# Case sensitivity in URL issue on Linux + NGinx + Kohana + php

Tags: linux, nginx, kohana

There is an issue/bug/feature/whatever on Linux + NGinx + Kohana :

We have to make sure that we keep all our file names in lowercase only.

We can't have anything like "`setUserServer.php`". It simply doesn't work. No idea why.
If we give the name of the same file as "`setuserserver.php`", it runs.

This problem doesn't exist on Windows + Apache + Kohana.

If anyone has an idea how to solve this, please do chime in this thread.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is sticking to the naming scheme of kohana: all files lower case

Windows by default is not case sensitive, and linux is. Can't "solve" that

Comment: Workaround: use lower-case filenames

Comment: An **ugly** workaround would be to set up a paritition with a `vfat` filesystem (which is case insensitive). To quickly try it out, you can create a virtual disk with copy your files it. See http://www.learnosity.com/techblog/index.cfm/2009/2/2/Noncase-sensitive-filesystem-on-Linux--HOWTO

Comment: @SpadXIII : "Like" :)   @Shawn Chin : Thats really ugly :)

Comment: If you're using Kohana, you could extend the find_file method to search for capitalized filenames. But imo the best solution is to stick with the proper naming scheme; which is all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixed case for a vendor libraries (loading by `include` or `require`), but [original Kohana's autoloader](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.1/master/classes/kohana/core.php#L486) will convert class names to lower case (as SpadXIII). So, possible solution is writing your own autoloader (or extend Kohana class) and use it instead/before standard.

PS. AFAIR, View class will work with files like `PageTemplate.php`